# Is it possible to use for loops inside print statement in Python

Tags: python, loops

Can I use print elements in a for loop with some conditions ?
Actually I have this block of code :

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1,1000):
    if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0 :
        sum+=i
print(sum)
```

and I want to convert it in a single line of code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a single line of code? Readability is very important, and condensing code into one line makes things less readable, and harder to debug.

Comment: I want browse integers from 1 to 1000 and add only the ones that are multiples of 3 or 5 to my sum

Comment: @BryanOakley I just want to have an example :) Thanks for pieces of advice :)

Comment: Yes, by making use of [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: next time please don't choose answer too soon, it keep away from more answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
print(sum(i for i in range(1,1000) if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0))
```

Note that I'm using the built-in function [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) here, which is different than you variable `sum` (in general you shouldn't use that as a name since it shadows the built-in function).

Comment: Thank you @arshajii, so it's not possible to do it with my variable sum by incrementing it with i value each time it satisfies my conditions ?

Comment: @mounaim If you want to use that type of approach, then you shouldn't really use a generator. Incrementing a variable according to some condition is better done by a simple for-loop as you have. Just be sure to rename the `sum` variable to something else (perhaps `total`).

Comment: Ok arshajii tanks for help :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce and lambda:

```
>>> reduce( lambda x,y: x +y, [i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0 ])
233168 
>>>
```

Or If you  want variable condition:

```
>>> def sum_it(Range, Divisible_by):
...    return sum([[0, i][any([i % n == 0 for n in Divisible_by])] for i in range(Range)])
...
>>> sum_it(1000, [3,5])
233168
>>> sum_it(1000, [3,6])
166833
>>>
```